# how to convert jpeg image to byte format

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am currently using Windows phone application to click a picture and I wanted to upload that image to a web service using HTTP post request. I don't want to use windows phone silverlight.

How can I send that image to the web service URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting image on http is just like posting any other file type. use following code snippet

```
public string PostFileUsingApi()
{
    string result = "";
    string param1 = "value1";

    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler()) {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8008") }) {
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);

            StorageFile storageFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
            Stream stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

            var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            StreamContent fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") {
                Name = "imagekey", //content key goes here
                FileName = "myimage"
            };

            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/bmp");

            requestContent.Add(fileContent);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ClientSecretKey", "ClientSecretValue");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/controller/UploadData?param1=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param1), requestContent).Result;

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
            } else {
                result = "";
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

install this package to resolve dependencies
https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client/

Comment: but there is no filestream for windows phone 8 application even i have added assembly reference to system.IO

Comment: i have edited code spinet to work with stream in windows phone. in sandbox environment you cant access file with IO Stream you need to get stream from StorageFile object in windows phone.

Comment: @Zain use `await` with `Async` Methods